# How are AWS snapshots persisted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

While trying to set a restored snapshot to keep from backing-up after launch, discovered that amazon automatically sets the backup retention period. It is not until after the instance is launched that I can set the backup retention period to zero.

In the AWS C# SDK documentation, the only case that states that the backup retention period cannot be set to zero is when the instance is a read replica. So in that case, why cannot I not set the backup retention period to zero on launch? Is the snapshot persisted on a disk somewhere? Or is it a running read replica kept alive to make restores faster?

Comment: Either you have misinterpreted the documentation, or the C# docs have an error.  You can't set retention to 0 if the instance is a *source to* read replicas (i.e. a master).  You have said that you "can't" set the retention period to 0 but you don't appear to have described what happens when you try.

Comment: Thanks for replying @michael-sqlbot!
I should have specified better, my apologies. I set the backup retention period to zero in a Terraform script and apply it for restoring from an RDS snapshot, it is restored but also does a backs up. 

Then when I run the script after the backup is done. The backup retention period gets set to zero and disabled; the backup windows is disabled.

C# SDK documentation says the backup retention period cannot be set to zero is when the instance is a read replica. Does this mean the snapshot is a read replica? Ultimately I do not want a backup upon restore.

Comment: After you run the script, a backup is made, but what is backup retention time actually set to, on the new instance, at that point?  Does the same behavior happen if you create the instance from a snapshot in the console?

Comment: ```From Terraform```
Backup and Restore

Automated backups
Enabled (7 Days)

Backup window
01:45-02:45 UTC (GMT)

```From the Console```
Backup and Restore

Automated backups
Enabled (7 Days)

Backup window
01:45-02:45 UTC (GMT)

In the console, backup windows and retention period are not options in the GUI.
Weird that Terraform and the C# SDK exposes this if it may only be allowed to be modified after launch. And if exposed initially in Terraform, why would it not restore and then run again to modify that field. 
I filed a question with Hashicorp, will report back

Comment: Interesting.  For some reason, I thought it was a console option.

Comment: This turned out to be a bug with Terraform and was solved in the version 1.38.0 of the AWS Provider. Reference is below:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug with Terraform and was solved in the version 1.38.0 of the AWS Provider. Reference is below:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5139